# Even the universe is infinite, it could keep expanding?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

the study showed  Cantor, that there are infinite types, the universe would be expanding as well as the possibility of Stephen Hawking.
http://phys.org/news/2015-02-big-quantum-equation-universe.html

Comment: Your body text doesn't really make much sense to me, could you re-write it to make it more clear?

Comment: Kyle Kanos, what I mean is, even if the universe is infinite he could grow?

Answer (score 1):

> *even if the universe is infinite he could grow?*

Yes. Even if you have a universe containing ∞ m³ every m³ can still double. ∞×2 will still be ∞, but all distances will have grown nevertheless. [Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw7MTOosfeU&t=29s), [Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKLqWj0FRyc&t=58s&list=PL7Yaf7nQHP3DSNGnCWvQOgz5A_EtQ-6sr&index=6), [Link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY8bB.gif)